# How to set text inside TextView to be in two lines?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

Is there any way to programmatically set text in `TextView` to be in two lines ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Type `\n` for a new line

```
This will be\ntwo lines
```

will look like

```
This will be
two lines
```

Also, be sure that the TextViews `setsingleline()` isn't set to true

Comment: Also check that you don't have `android:maxLines` limitation in your XML.

Answer (score 9):

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("First Line \n this is Second Line");
setContentView(tv);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\n` to insert a line break in your textview.

Like this:

```
playing.setText( "STATION: \n" + stations.get( position ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your TextView has couple of lines of code in xml:

`android:lines="2"
android:singleLine="false"`

by default **`android:singleLine`** is true. So you can set it in XML or in Java code i.e. :

```
txtNextLine.setSingleLine(false);
txtNotActivate.setText("first line\n"+"second line");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: `singleLine` is deprecated , use `maxLine = "1"`